# Get ANOVA summary statistics from each unique factor separately

Tags: r, anova, summary

Hi, I have a large dataset with isotope values for multiple species per season on different locations from which I performed an ANOVA:

```
Anova <- Isotopes %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(model = aov(d15N~Season+Location, data = Isotopes))

Anova$model
```

I would like to see the summary of this test for each unique species separately. How can I get this data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question, you can use lapply:

```
# Reproduce a similar dataset
    Anova <- iris %>% 
      mutate(new_var = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = nrow(.), replace = T)) %>%
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      do(model = aov(Sepal.Length~Petal.Width+new_var, data = .))

summ <- lapply(Anova$model,summary)
names(summ) <- Anova$Species
summ
```

> $setosa
> Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
> Petal.Width  1  0.471  0.4709   3.919 0.0538 .
> new_var      2  0.090  0.0450   0.374 0.6898
> Residuals   46  5.527  0.1202
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> $versicolor
> Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
> Petal.Width  1  3.899   3.899  22.432 2.12e-05 ***
> new_var      2  1.162   0.581   3.344   0.0441 *
> Residuals   46  7.994   0.174
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> $virginica
> Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
> Petal.Width  1  1.566  1.5656   4.049 0.0501 .
> new_var      2  0.459  0.2295   0.593 0.5566
> Residuals   46 17.788  0.3867
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Comment: For a pure-er 'tidyvese' approach, one can set the names inside the stack: ```Anova <- iris %>% 
  mutate(new_var = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = nrow(.), replace = T)) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(model = aov(Sepal.Length~Petal.Width+new_var, data = .))%>%
  pull(model, name = Species) %>%
  purrr::map(summary) 
 ```